# SQL Select: Using CTE as dataset for IN clause - syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, common-table-expression, sql

While implementing this new idea `Common Table Expressions` in my query:

```
SELECT ..... FROM .... WHERE ... IN 
(
 ;with CTEName as
   (
      CTE syntax goes here
   )
     SELECT .... FROM CTEName
)
GROUP BY ....
```

still getting the following query errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

is this a valid usage of CTE?
Thanks.

Comment: that's not how you reference a CTE.....

Comment: Here you will find the answer http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Comment: `;` is the statement terminator in SQL - you will *never* find it in the middle of a statement. Just thought I should point that out, since it might help you reason around similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH    CTEName as
        (
        -- CTE syntax goes here
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   myfield IN 
        (
        SELECT  ctefield
        FROM    CTEName
        )
GROUP BY
        myotherfield
```

In other words, the `CTE` should be defined before all other commands (as if they were actual tables).

Also note that the semicolon (`;`) is normally not required. However, the `CTE` syntax was implemented in `SQL Server` after it had already introduced the keyword `WITH` for its own purposes, so implicit statement breaking does not work with `CTE` anymore:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WITH    q AS (SELECT 1)
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

It's hard to define where the `WITH` is used in the first or second statement here.

So it is considered a best practice to always prepend `WITH` with a semicolon so that you could easily cut and paste it anywhere in your code without having to worry about whether it is a first statement in a batch or not.